# Which ORMs support Attribute based Client Side and Server Side Validation in ASP.NET MVC3?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, orm, asp.net-mvc-3

I really like the way Entity Frame Code First integrates with MVC3 validation detailed here:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/10/class-level-model-validation-with-ef-code-first-and-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx

My question is what other ORM's can be used with MVC3 like this? I'm particularly curious about NHibernate since it seems to be the ORM of choice of many MVC 1 & 2 sites. Are there any add-ons or options to enable attribute based validation that works both client and server side in MVC3?

EDIT:
tvanfosson cleared up part of the question put I'd also like to know how validation at the class level works in other ORMs. Will they automatically call **Validate** on an **IValidatableObject**?

For instance I can have this class in EF CF:

```
public class Person 
{
  [Key]
  public int Id { get; set; }
  [Email]
  public string HomeEmail { get; set;}
}
```

And then using the DataAnnotationsExtensions NuGet package I can run the following code (outside of MVC even) and get an error.

```
using (SiteDB db = new SiteDB()) {
  db.Persons.Add(new Person() { HomeEmail = "Invalid" });
  db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The DataAnnotations work with the model binder and validation parts of the framework.  If you can decoration your model with the attributes, it will work with the baked-in validation.  I've used it with both EF and LINQ2SQL as well as view-only models.

Comment: That clears up part of my question. Do other ORMs also have the "Automatic Validation Enforcement" at the class level meaning they automatically call "Validate"?

Comment: @CDeutsch - MVC will do the validation at the model level so if your view model validation is the same, then you should be ok.  If you want to revalidate your entity models or your entity models are different than your view models, then the answer is mixed.  You can extend LINQ2SQL to use the annotations, but you'd have to do take care of this yourself.  It does have the hooks to call your validation code if you write it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
Linq to sql
Entity Framework
Nhibernate
Fluent Nhibernate
```

Regards